# Ethernet Connection drops occasionally at home

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a weird problem with my ethernet port connection at home. I did my own ethernet cabling with proper tools and tests at home. Everything seemed to work. Pings were fast and no package was lost with high transmission speed (Gigabit connection). After I was convinced everything is working properly, I started to use my ethernet network. My raspberry Pis are working fine over ethernet, however, my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Lenovo T450s disconnects randomly. Here are the symptoms:

- Ethernet connection indicator doesn't display the connection loss.
- It mostly happens while I am browsing and in between opening a new
  page/clicking a new link.
- Website takes forever to load and eventually ending up with error in the browser.
- Whenever I see that the website takes unusually long to load, I ping my cable modem, in which packages arrive the modem and come back. And then **the connection recovers**. After some testing, I realized that the **connection only recovers after pinging the modem!** Interestingly, first package (after the connection problem) takes ~1007ms and then the rest ~0.5ms. Somehow, the first package takes too long. Also, I started to **ping the modem with 2-3 seconds interval**, which **prevented** any further disruption.
- All the other devices connected to the modem and the Internet through WiFi or Ethernet, work perfectly fine! Including, raspberry Pi, Windows machines etc.
- The same notebook, works also fine at work on ethernet.

Somehow, my Ubuntu notebook has a problem with my small home ethernet network. My assumption at this point was that Ubuntu is turning off my ethernet card or do some power saving, which makes it inaccessible. Pinging revives or keeps it awake. But I have this issue, while I am charging my laptop.

How can I solve this? Any ideas?

Forgot to mention... I made a script to collect some information through the **ethtool** right after the connection loss and revival (for comparison). There are no apparent differences (checked with diff). But here is the output after (during) the connection loss.

```
--version
_________
ethtool version 3.13
-a
_________
Pause parameters for eth0:
Autonegotiate:  on
RX:     on
TX:     on

-c
_________
Coalesce parameters for eth0:
Adaptive RX: off  TX: off
stats-block-usecs: 0
sample-interval: 0
pkt-rate-low: 0
pkt-rate-high: 0

rx-usecs: 3
rx-frames: 0
rx-usecs-irq: 0
rx-frames-irq: 0

tx-usecs: 0
tx-frames: 0
tx-usecs-irq: 0
tx-frames-irq: 0

rx-usecs-low: 0
rx-frame-low: 0
tx-usecs-low: 0
tx-frame-low: 0

rx-usecs-high: 0
rx-frame-high: 0
tx-usecs-high: 0
tx-frame-high: 0

-i
_________
driver: e1000e
version: 2.3.2-k
firmware-version: 0.2-3
bus-info: 0000:00:19.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
-g
_________
Ring parameters for eth0:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:     4096
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:     4096
Current hardware settings:
RX:     256
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:     256

-S
_________
NIC statistics:
     rx_packets: 4923045
     tx_packets: 2764542
     rx_bytes: 6044576522
     tx_bytes: 515265291
     rx_broadcast: 140452
     tx_broadcast: 1805
     rx_multicast: 34355
     tx_multicast: 972
     rx_errors: 0
     tx_errors: 0
     tx_dropped: 0
     multicast: 34355
     collisions: 0
     rx_length_errors: 0
     rx_over_errors: 0
     rx_crc_errors: 0
     rx_frame_errors: 0
     rx_no_buffer_count: 0
     rx_missed_errors: 0
     tx_aborted_errors: 0
     tx_carrier_errors: 0
     tx_fifo_errors: 0
     tx_heartbeat_errors: 0
     tx_window_errors: 0
     tx_abort_late_coll: 0
     tx_deferred_ok: 0
     tx_single_coll_ok: 0
     tx_multi_coll_ok: 0
     tx_timeout_count: 0
     tx_restart_queue: 0
     rx_long_length_errors: 0
     rx_short_length_errors: 0
     rx_align_errors: 0
     tx_tcp_seg_good: 41837
     tx_tcp_seg_failed: 0
     rx_flow_control_xon: 0
     rx_flow_control_xoff: 0
     tx_flow_control_xon: 0
     tx_flow_control_xoff: 0
     rx_csum_offload_good: 4888272
     rx_csum_offload_errors: 69
     rx_header_split: 0
     alloc_rx_buff_failed: 0
     tx_smbus: 0
     rx_smbus: 1274
     dropped_smbus: 0
     rx_dma_failed: 0
     tx_dma_failed: 0
     rx_hwtstamp_cleared: 0
     uncorr_ecc_errors: 0
     corr_ecc_errors: 0
-t (test)
_________
The test result is PASS
The test extra info:
Register test  (offline)     0
Eeprom test    (offline)     0
Interrupt test (offline)     0
Loopback test  (offline)     0
Link test   (on/offline)     0
```

---

**EDIT:**
I have tried to to compile and install the recent **3.3.5** version of e1000e... Both worked without any errors. But with or without reboot `ethtool -i eth0` tells me that I still have **2.3.2-k**. Here is the make install output:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-93-generic/build CC=gcc SUBDIRS=/home/<username>/Desktop/IT/e1000e-3.3.5/src modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-93-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-93-generic'
gzip -c ../e1000e.7 > e1000e.7.gz
# remove all old versions of the driver
find /lib/modules/3.13.0-93-generic -name e1000e.ko -exec rm -f {} \; || true
find /lib/modules/3.13.0-93-generic -name e1000e.ko.gz -exec rm -f {} \; || true
install -D -m 644 e1000e.ko /lib/modules/3.13.0-93-generic/updates/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
/sbin/depmod -a 3.13.0-93-generic || true
install -D -m 644 e1000e.7.gz /usr/share/man/man7/e1000e.7.gz
man -c -P'cat > /dev/null' e1000e || true
e1000e.
```

**INFO:**
I have finally created the dkms.conf

```
MAKE="make -C src/ KERNELDIR=/lib/modules/${kernelver}/build"
CLEAN="make -C src/ clean"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME=e1000e
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION=src/
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION="/kernel/updates/dkms"
PACKAGE_NAME=e1000e
PACKAGE_VERSION=3.3.5
REMAKE_INITRD=yes
```

I also have followed [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS) instructions.

**Sadly the new driver also has the same issue.**

Comment: You may need to build yourself an updated e1000e driver for your ethernet device. You have driver version 2.3.2, and version 3.3.5 is available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/e1000e%20stable/3.3.5/. Do you know how to compile software? Do you know how to use DKMS?

Comment: I used backports for my wifi, which solved wifi issues. Can I use the same route or is this not a "module", anyhow I guess, I can compile it...

Comment: Yes, this is also a kernel module. If an updated version is available in backports, go for it. In any case, you'll want to use DKMS for all of your self-compiled modules.

Comment: I have a question though. I have compiled the e1000, do I do make install or dkms install? I don't get this part... I could install the newer wifi module from backports by using make && make install.

Comment: If you compile and MAKE INSTALL any kernel module, it will work... until the next time Software Updater updates your Ubuntu kernel, and then those drivers will not be there and won't work. That's where DKMS comes in. It'll recompile and install the drivers automatically every time there's a kernel change/update. Learning DKMS takes a little time though. If you find a dkms.conf file at the top level of your source code, then the hardest part has already been done for you.

Comment: I tried to install it with a make install in order to test, before dealing with DKMS, but I can't have the newer version installed. Please see my edit on the question. I didn't have this issue with the backports. But in backports, I do not have the e1000e driver but only igb.

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed above... download the newer e1000e driver at https://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/e1000e%20stable/3.3.5/, compile it using **make** and **make install**. This will install the new kernel module, but the old kernal module is still loaded in the current kernel. So, in terminal, do a **sudo rmmod e1000e** (your ethernet connection will now drop), then do a **sudo modprobe e1000e**, and that should load the new kernel module and restart your ethernet connection. Then you can do a **sudo modinfo e1000e** to confirm that you're running on the new kernel module.

Then, did you find a dkms.conf file at the top level of your source code? If so, the hard work to use dkms has been done. Install dkms (if it's not already) using Synaptic. Short answer... you'll copy the source to /usr/src, then do a dkms add, build, install. You have to review the man's for more learning. The **dkms status** command will show you the current state.

Comment: Thanks a lot! rmmod and modprobe did the trick. There is no dkms.conf but I will learn it if I will need it. I can test now, if the newer driver works better.

Comment: Glad it works better! Please vote and accept my answer if you can. Cheers, Al

Comment: So far it seems to work! Once I had Ubuntu (which is odd) but I cannot trace it back to the new driver (nothing in the logs). Therefore, I will accept this as an answer. I will also look into the dkms. I cannot vote it up (due to my reputation).

Comment: I also have finally created the dkms.conf and used DKMS for the new driver release. See info part of my question.

Comment: Great news! Please vote on my answer. Cheers, Al

Comment: I still can't not enough rep.

Comment: It seems now that the problem persists...

Comment: What is your MTU setting in Ubuntu, and your router? Do you have cable or dsl internet? Do you have ipv6 enabled or disabled? Try a commercial ethernet cable. Cheers, Al